# Como guardar imagen con JFileChooser en X ruta

Tags: java, java-swing, jfilechooser

Estoy intentando guardar una imagen previamente seleccionada con **JFileChooser** en un `jLabel`.

Al buscar la imagen, me carga correctamente en el `jLabel`. Seguidamente intento guardarla con un evento **ActionPerfomed** en un `jButton`, me deja seleccionar la ruta donde quiero guardarlo pero no me la guarda - no está visible en el escritorio. ¿Por qué?

¿Se puede elegir guardar en el directorio actual del proyecto o en una ruta concreta como `"/users/nick/desktop"`? ¿Preseleccionar el tipo de archivo como "**jpg o png**" por si al usuario se le olvida agregar la extensión?

**Código de abrir fichero:**

```
private void button_elegirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG & JPEG & PNG", "jpg", "jpeg", "png");
    fc.setFileFilter(filter);

    int seleccion = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    fc.setDialogTitle("Buscar imagen...");

    if (seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
        ImageIcon i = null;
        try {
            i = new ImageIcon(f.toURI().toURL());
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en el formato o al encontrar la imagen.");
            Logger.getLogger(CargarImagenes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(i.getImage().getScaledInstance(label_foto.getWidth(), label_foto.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        button_guardar.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**Código de guardar fichero:**

```
private void button_guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int seleccion = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
    fc.setDialogTitle("Guardar");

    if (seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        //¿Se puede elegir predeterminada la ruta donde guardar? ¿y la extensión?
        String ruta = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué se debe mi error?